# sql pass result to another calcuation

Tags: sql-server

how do I pass my result to another calculation as I get a

> invalid column name profilhøjde

what is the correct way to do this?

```
         select * from
        (select ([brede]*[Profil])/100 as "profilhøjde"
        from [Tabel].[dæk]
        )a

        select * from
        (select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "omkreds for 10 tommer",
          (Select ([profilhøjde]*2+@diameter11)*PI()) AS "omkreds for 11 tommer",
          (Select ([profilhøjde]*2+@diameter12)*PI()) AS "omkreds for 12 tommer"
        )a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    declare @diameter10 int

     select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
,("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
, ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter11)*PI() as "diameter 11 tommer" 
, ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 12 tommer" 
 from
        (select ([brede]*[Profil])/100 as "profilhøjde"
        from [Tabel].[dæk]
        )a
```

Comment: would it be possible to not showing the result for the diameters sometinhg similar to `SET`

Comment: sorry iam not getting what u are saying..@ominidata explain clearly

Comment: abit like when i use `SET @tommer10 = 10
SET @diameter10 = @tommer10 * 25.4
` instead of select so i dont see the result for thoose

Comment: u need  to declare first after that u need set  value for tomer10 ..@ominidata

Comment: please declare with symbol
declare  tommer10 int =10,
         diameter10 int
  SET diameter10  = tommer10 * 25.4
  select diameter10  @ominidata

Comment: i think what op asking for is something similar to his `SET @tommer10 = 10` for `("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
,("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
, ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter11)*PI() as "diameter 11 tommer"` for later proccesing so it doesn't give him the result for that calculation

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE

[Here More On CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;with a as
(
select ([brede]*[Profil])/100 as "profilhøjde"
from [Tabel].[dæk]
)

  select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
,("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
, ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter11)*PI() as "diameter 11 tommer" 
, ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 12 tommer"
from a
```

Comment: what if i want to have multiple calculation from that one like 

 `select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 10 tommer" 
select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter11)*PI() as "diameter 11 tommer"
 select ("profilhøjde" *2 + @diameter10)*PI() as "diameter 12 tommer" 
from a`

Comment: it will work and also subquery will also work ..@ominidata

Comment: @ominidata Editted the answer.

Comment: @ominidata You should be including information like this as an edit to the question so everyone can see it, rather than burying it in the comments of one particular answer.